# How to retrieve rows of a table and show them in dropdown box?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am using the following code to retrieve a list of items, and show them in a dropdown list.

The problem is that I need to pass IDs as ID of each option and names as values of each option of dropdownbox. As type of Ids are int I need to convert them to string to use them as keys of HashMap.

I am wondering if there is any alternative method, to avoid conversion.

```
List <ListRows> results = session.createQuery("SELECT new 
       com.example.ListRows (d.id,d.name) FROM MyTable d").list();

for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++)
{

    myhashmap.put(ConvertToString(results.get(i).getID()),
                  results.get(i).getName();
}

 return myhashmap;
}



public String ConvertToString(int item){
      Convert item to String
      return StrItem;
   }
```

**ListRows.java**

```
public class ListRows {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    //Constructor 
    // getters and setters
}
```

**JSP**

```
 <s:select name="development"
                          id="myrows"
                          label="Rows"
                          list="myhashmap"
                          onchange="View(this.value)"
                          headerKey = "-1"
                          headerValue=" "
                          />
```

Comment: Why can't you use int as a key type in your map?

Comment: And even if you need (and you don't) to convert an int to String, why do you need a custom method instead of using `String.valueOf()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont create hashmap and just return List will work.
Try below code,

```
<s:select name="development" list="%{results}" listKey="%{id}"
            listValue="%{name}" onchange="View(this.value)" label="Rows" headerKey = "-1" headerValue = " "></s:select>
```